# Does EnterAir allow boarding of disabled person with walking sticks?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, accessibility, denied-boarding

We booked some holiday with my girlfriend through a travel agency and apparently the airline is EnterAir which I've never traveled with before. My girlfriend has a disability that creates some mobility problems for her, so she is using walking sticks like these, otherwise she isn't able to walk. 
[image]

Her disability is visible, so there is no doubt that she needs them to walk.

My question is, does anyone with this kind of issue ever traveled with EnterAir and did they have a problem boarding, passing security, etc?

Comment: Have you checked with the airline regarding eg assisted boarding?

Comment: As long as she has the sticks she doesn't need any assistance to do anything. Sorry if it wasn't clear. My question is if the airline itself creates a problem(due to security reasons or something).

Comment: In UK (at least) it is illegal to discriminate against a disability. If the airline won't allow boarding with the sticks they must provide alternative means of boarding.

Comment: @randomDude What I meant was, have you contacted the airline to find out?

Comment: The EnterAir web site says this on the [Buy a Ticket page](https://www.enterair.pl/en/buy-ticket): _'Individual Passengers who require special assistance and care are required to inform Enter Air ltd., up-front , by sending an e-mail to support@enterair.pl.'_. I'd send them an email just to avoid any problems.

Comment: [Information for special care passengers](https://www.enterair.pl/uploads/OWP%20maj%202017/Enter%20Air%20special%20care%20passengers%20excerpt%20ENG.pdf), [Guidebook for disabled passengers](https://www.ulc.gov.pl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2506:guide-for-disabled-passengers&catid=280&Itemid=1502&lang=en), [APPLICATION SHEET FOR PASSENGER REQUIRING SPECIAL ASSISTANCE](https://www.enterair.pl/uploads/Formularz%20MEDIF%20Enter%20Air%20ang.pdf)

Comment: "Air carriers in addition to the transport of medical equipment are also required to transport no more than two pieces of mobility equipment per disabled person or person with reduced mobility, including electric wheelchairs". Walking sticks should be the least of their problems. Get a medical certificate from a doctor to be sure, and notify the airline beforehand so there's a mention in the booking.

Comment: Just an update, everything was fine. As long as the sticks pass security, the airline had no problem bringing them inside the cabin. No prior notification was needed as well.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's why every airport provides wheelchair service.

Answer (score 3):

[Regulation (EC) No 1107/2006 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 5 July 2006 concerning the rights of disabled persons and persons with reduced mobility when travelling by air](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32006R1107)

> In addition to medical equipment, transport of up to two pieces of mobility equipment per disabled person or person with reduced mobility, including electric wheelchairs (subject to advance warning of 48 hours and to possible limitations of space on board the aircraft, and subject to the application of relevant legislation concerning dangerous goods).

On [Wheelchair Air Travel: Tips And Tricks To Get It Right](http://www.reducedmobility.eu/20130621324/The-News/wheelchair-air-travel-tips-and-tricks-to-get-it-right.html) it notes:

> European legislation applies to all flights departing from any airport inside the European Union, and to incoming flights operated by European airlines only.

The biggest challenge will be security. There are two things you must do: one is to contact the airline at least 48 hours prior even if you don't use an electronic wheelchair becaues this will allow them to arrange assistance at the airport. Ask them specifically to do so. Also, arrive early to the airport, two hours is strongly recommended. Some airports will get you through a special security lane, for example the [Prague airport](https://www.prg.aero/en/persons-reduced-mobility-and-orientation) clearly has this. EnterAir uses Warsaw airport, the relevant [page](https://www.lotnisko-chopina.pl/en/passenger-rights.html#tab30) asks you to use the intercoms when there and this [PDF](https://www.lotnisko-chopina.pl/uploads/user_files/kdp-PRM-01%20Code%20of%20good%20practice%20for%20provisionof%20ground%20hanling%20services.pdf) says:

> The scope of assistance available at Chopin Airport ...
>   help and assistance during ... security screening before departure;

When browsing this PDF you can also find service standards and that it takes 15 minutes longer to get assistance if you are not pre-booked. Even if pre-booked, they state in the worst case you might need to wait for 30 minutes for assistance. This is why you should be early.